# train a model to get summary from a story

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to create a model that trains on some data (providing summary of some stories) and the model should be able to provide the summary of the given text or story.

kindly suggest some model for the same.

Comment: Your question is too general and is off topic on SO.

Comment: I need to develop a model which reads a paragraph and tells the summary of the passage. This is kind of telling the moral of the story after reading the story. I need to know what algorithm can be used.
I am sure that this will be a classification model.

Comment: If we train the model with some general morals and then if a similar story comes the model should be able to tell the moral associated

Answer (score 0):

You can try as a baseline [pre-trained model](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/summarization/summariser.html) from gensim library. As a more advanced version, I would suggest looking into [PEGASUS](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/06/pegasus-state-of-art-model-for.html) - a State-of-the-Art Model for abstractive text summarization